# RecyclerView: Reset other items state from current item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm using EasyFlipView to flip my View in my RecyclerViews onLongClick, which is working as expected. the issue I'm running into is when flipping a view, detecting that its flipped and flipping it back over when flipping a new view. Basically the same as only checking one item in a RecyclerView at a time, as simple as that seems, I can't figure it out.

EasyFlipView: https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView

Comment: you are saying that your other view got flip when you scroll right ?????

Comment: No scrolling isn't an issue, I just want to unflip the first view I flipped when I flip another view

Comment: Right now I get it  is there any property you are saving like Boolean in your data model that you are using in recycler view

Comment: Just a Note object which contains some strings

Comment: Ok so just edit your post and add some of your code   your adapters and some of your model